# Emacs freezes when minimizing frame on OSX

Tags: osx

I have had the issue that emacs will lock up (and need to be force quit)
on occasion when I minimize it.  I am almost always in org-mode, but
otherwise I can see any pattern, except that it happens while it is minimized.

I have scoured the world for a fix to this.  Does anyone know how to fix this, or at least how to figure out why it is happening?

I'm on OSX 10.11 with Emacs 24.5

Comment: Where did you get your 24.5?  Did you get it from the tried and true generic build all packaged into one nice and neat `Emacs.app` from https://emacsformacosx.com/ ?  Did you build it yourself?  Did you use homebrew or macports?  Have you tried another build from a different source to see if your problem magically goes away?  If you are using homebrew or macports, perhaps you are accessing other components that might not be present in the most generic build from https://emacsformacosx.com/  For example, if Emacs sees available ingredients when building from source, they will become a part.

Comment: Of course, most everyone here will want to know if you have tried with a minimal Emacs user-configuration -- i.e., as close as you can get to `emacs -q` as possible.  If you have tried everything else and want to assist the Emacs team to debug the issue, you can build from Emacs source and then launch Emacs under gdb from the Terminal.app and then get a backtrace when it locks up.  In such a case, you would leave the source files where they are while debugging.  You might also want to try playing with the Emacs 25 release candidate, or the master branch build.

Comment: Note that Emacs 25 and later (e.g., master branch) have several important bug fixes relating to frames, including sizes and placement.  The only time I fire up 24.5 for OSX is when I'm trying to answer a question for someone on an Emacs forum.

Comment: @lawlist thanks!  I had used EmacsForOSX, I am not trying a brew solution, but that is still 24.5.  If that fails I will try 25-rc2.  Thanks.  If any of these work, I will create a solution to my own issue.  (If you want to create that solution ticket for me then, I can also accept yours.)  either way.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using the ``not yet stable'' 25-rc2 build of Emacs for a month without any lockup issues.  So it seems @lawless is correct, and this did fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue still exists in the latests stable Emacs 27.1 version.
It has been reproduced using a linux machine under the following conditions:

- Emacs 27.1 built with Lucid toolkit
- Desktop manager: any running Gnome Shell
- From your Emacs GUI session hit `C-z`
- Comeback to the minimized frame: it is unresponsive

The reason is that Mutter, starting from [this commit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/commit/aec3edb1cc5ae386efbb08ec7414173478ff0d89)
, do not unmap minimized windows.
Note that Muffin WM follows the same approach as Mutter; that means, you might see the same issue with Linux Mint.

Emacs has applied a patch that will be available in the next
release (27.2).